# Jitterbit doesn't allow me to log into Sandbox

Tags: jitterbit

I just downloaded Jitterbit for the first time, as I heard it's a great tool for loading data, so I wanted to learn it.

Unfortunately I cannot log in - I created a new project, and entered my username and password and clicked sandbox. We don't use security tokens, and I double and triple checked my password.

I keep getting an error message saying "Not Found". Is there anything else I need to set up before connecting?

[image: Jitterbit]

Tia.

Comment: What do you see against your user record (assuming you are using your login details) under login history? Sometimes it's also worth trying the instance url, e.g. https://cs24.salesforce.com (if it's a newly refreshed sandbox for example)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue some time ago when installing Jitterbit on my new machine. Uninstalling and reinstalling worked for me.

See more info in [this thread](https://getsatisfaction.com/dataloader/topics/not-found-404) on the Jitterbit support forum.